# Redis AUTH command in Python

Tags: python, redis

I'm using [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) binding in Python 2 to connect to my Redis server. The server requires a password. I don't know how to `AUTH` after making the connection in Python.

The following code does not work:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis()
r.auth('pass')
```

It says:

> 'StrictRedis' object has no attribute 'auth'

Also,

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(auth='pass')
```

does not work either. No such keyword argument.

I've used Redis binding in other languages before, and usually the method name coincides with the Redis command. So I would guess `r.auth` will send `AUTH`, but unfortunately it does not have this method.

So what is the standard way of `AUTH`? Also, why call this `StrictRedis`? What does `Strict` mean here?

Comment: Rather poor effort on documenting the project, it seems. On the GH page and on pypi there's no explicit link to the official documentation. I had to Google it to find https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ and https://kushal.fedorapeople.org/redis-py/html/index.html. Both are automatically generated from the code.

Comment: the only place where they mention authentication is: `on_connect()
    Initialize the connection, authenticate and select a database`. Ask andymccurdy, Redis says redis-py is mature and supported, the way to go.

Comment: @Pynchia Thanks! The doc solved it. Please find below.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Thanks to the hints from the comments. I found the answer from https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

It says

```
class redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, password=None, socket_timeout=None, connection_pool=None, charset='utf-8', errors='strict', unix_socket_path=None)
```

So `AUTH` is in fact `password` passed by keyword argument.

Comment: good, well-done! I'm glad I pointed you to the right direction.

Comment: what about username?  I can't find username anywhere.

Comment: @JustinThomas What username? Does redis have a username? I haven't used it ever since.

Comment: @JustinThomas there is no username for redis

Comment: Thanks for posting this, helped me too!

Comment: To clear things up for newcommers: If you do not provide a username, it will try to authenticate the default user. There can however be multiple users.

Answer (score 8):

This worked great for me.

```
redis_db = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0, password='yourPassword')
```

If you have Redis running on a different server, you have to remember to add **bind 0.0.0.0** after **bind 127.0.0.1** in the config (/etc/redis/redis.conf).
On Ubuntu this should only output one line with 0.0.0.0:

```
sudo netstat -lnp | grep redis
```

My result for netstat:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6089/redis-server 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use password instead of AUTH:

````
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost',port=6379,db=0,password='Prabhat')
>>> print(r)
Redis<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
>>>```
````

Answer (score 3):

I saw many comments saying Redis does not support username, well it does:

```
user_connection = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6380, username='dvora', password='redis', decode_responses=True)
```